# How to set the orthographic camera to match a specific width?

Tags: camera, orthographic

Consider a simple setup where the camera is facing a plane orthogonal. For further simplicity, assume that the camera is located at X=0 and facing along the Y-axis. The plane is also centered to the Y-axis. Now the goal is to set the camera viewing area in a way so that the left and right boundaries of the camera do exactly align with the left and right boundaries of the plane.

Of course, this should be done by entering the according numbers at the right place and not by tweaking the orthographic scale of the camera or similar, until it looks that it fits...

The background is that I want to render planes with textures of a specific width in pixels. I want to preserve that width in the output. I.e. when the texture is say 3000 pixels wide, the render output is also 3000 pixels wide and the plane fits horizontally the camera width, then there should be no horizontal interpolation during texture mapping and the initial texture quality is kept.

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: maybe I don't understand your question, the output size you define in format > resolution, and you could think of the ortho camera scale in Blender units, so if your image is on a 5 meters width plane you set the ortho scale to 5... I may be missing something though?

Comment: @alambre I didn’t know that… #LSNED

Comment: of course, but I misunderstand every other question that's why the comment... something else to consider here would be color management, sometimes a rendered texture doesn't look the same as the original picture, you got to see what works the best

Comment: @alambre Yes, intuitively I also thought that it should fit when I set the orthographic scale to the width of the plane (i.e. plane width=1 => orthographic scale=1). However, there is some relation with the actual resolution. For instance when the plane is 1m x 7.17m, and I set the resolution to 100x717 pixels, then I have to set the orthographic scale to 7.17. This method seems to work, at least. What you mention with the rendered texture quality is true indeed. Even if I feed the texture without a shader, I'm loosing contrast. I think I will ask this separately here....

Comment: yes, it's not the width of the plane, it's the width or the height, the biggest of both dimensions...

Comment: Yes, it's the biggest of both that has to be chosen. Anyway, I can deal with this now. I also found a solution for the image quality problem deep in Blender's manual....  The most important thing is associated with the "Color Management" whose default transition is set to "Filmic". This needs to be set to "Standard" in case the input image colors are to be preserved. Then the Render-Sampling needs to be set to 1 (at least for Eevee - Cycles I'm not sure). Together with the proper orthographic setting I can produce now an output identical with the texture (for testing only, of course...).